# Arrange the list alphabetically python2

Tags: python-2.7

A list of String, sort the list alphabetically
if there are upper case and lower case letters, sort them together by
ignoring case while sorting.if the same word is repeated with
different case, print lower case first, followed by the one with upper case.
while sorting ensure numbers are printed prior to alphabets. Ignore
punctuation's and special characters while sorting

Input
First line contains  an integer N, denoting the number of strings in the list
Then next N line contains the words in the list

Output
Print the list of words after sorting in increasing alphabetical order .Please 
make sure your output matches the samples.

Below is the code

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input():
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

INPUT

```
5
USA
UK
Germany
Australia
Canada
```

Output

```
Australia
Canada
Germany
UK
USA
```

I am also trying to do something but doesn't resolve the whole situation

```
var = ['USA','UK','Germany','Australia','Canada']
s = sorted(var, key=lambda v: (v.upper(), v[0].islower()))
print(s)
```

Comment: Your current code is sorting the characters within each line, not the lines relative to one another.

Comment: @Blckknght How we can achieve this?

Comment: You probably need to read all the words into a list, then sort it at the end. I'm not sure I understand fully what your end condition is on getting the words. Is the first input supposed to be the number of words that will be on the later lines?

Comment: "Doesn't resolve the whole situation" doesn't tell us much. What exactly is your code doing wrong?

Comment: @glibdud the issue is while I am passing the input as I mentioned above and do sorted(line) I get the below error message     sys.stdout.write(sorted(line))
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Comment: @glibdud Moreover you pass the integer value that tells how many words you can pass and then sort only those words and doesn't show the integer number

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a sorting function that hope does what you want. The whole ignore special characters is a little funky.

```
def sorting(word):
  new_word = ""
  for char in word:
    # Remove special characters
    if not char.isalnum():
      continue
    # Switch case
    new_word += char.upper() if char.islower() else char.lower()
  return (new_word.upper(), new_word)
```

Decided to switch the cases since for you lower case must be ordered before upper case.

In use:

```
words = []
n = int(input("Number of words: "))
for i in range(n):
  word = raw_input("> ")
  words.append(word)
result = sorted(words, key=sorting)
print(result)
```

Shows:

```
Number of words: 5
> USA
> UK
> Germany
> Australia
> Canada
['Australia', 'Canada', 'Germany', 'UK', 'USA']
```

Can also be called like this, gives the same result:

```
var = ['USA','UK','Germany','Australia','Canada']
s = sorted(var, key=sorting)
print(s)
```

Another more complex example to show the result:

```
Number of words: 5
> ASD
> asd
> asD
> aSD
> .asd
['asd', '.asd', 'asD', 'aSD', 'ASD']
```

Depending on the order of input `.asd` could be first or second, this you get for ignoring the special characters.